# How to pass parameters dynamically to map function on GAE mapreduce?

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

I need to run a mapreduce job that is dynamic in the sense that parameters need to be passed to the map and reduce functions each time the mapreduce job is run (e.g., in response to a user request).

How do I accomplish this? I could not see anywhere in the documentation how to do dynamic processing at runtime for map and reduce.

```
class MatchProcessing(webapp2.RequestHandler):

  def get(self):
      requestKeyID=int(self.request.get('riderbeeRequestID'))
      userKey=self.request.get('userKey')
      pipeline = MatchingPipeline(requestKeyID, userKey)
      pipeline.start()
      self.redirect(pipeline.base_path + "/status?root=" + pipeline.pipeline_id)


class MatchingPipeline(base_handler.PipelineBase):
    def run(self, requestKeyID, userKey):
        yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapreducePipeline(
            "riderbee_matching",
            "tasks.matchingMR.riderbee_map",
            "tasks.matchingMR.riderbee_reduce",
            "mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader",
            "mapreduce.output_writers.BlobstoreOutputWriter",
            mapper_params={
                "entity_kind": "models.rides.RiderbeeRequest",
                "requestKeyID": requestKeyID,
                "userKey": userKey,
            },
            reducer_params={
                "mime_type": "text/plain",
            },
            shards=16)


def riderbee_map(riderbeeRequest):
    # would like to access the requestKeyID and userKey parameters that were passed in mapper_params
    # so that we can do some processing based on that

    yield (riderbeeRequest.user.email, riderbeeRequest.key().id())


def riderbee_reduce(key, values):
    # would like to access the requestKeyID and userKey parameters that were passed earlier, perhaps through reducer_params
    # so that we can do some processing based on that

    yield "%s: %s\n" % (key, len(values))
```

Help please?

Comment: FYI ... here is how to send data to a job in Java - http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2011/11/passing-parameters-to-mappers-and.html

Comment: Hmmm. The link you give points to Hadoop stuff. This is for GAE MapReduce ...

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure you can just specify parameters in mapper_parameters, and read them from the context module. See http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/UserGuidePython#Mapper_parameters for more details.

Comment: Except that in the link you refer to those parameters are not dynamic (ie., not passed programmatically at runtime) rather they are read from mapreduce.yaml which is static. That is, unless I am misunderstanding how this would work

Comment: In the code you use above, there's a mapper_params param to the MapreducePipeline constructor; there's also a mapreduce_parameters param. These are the equivalent of the params that come from the yaml file. See the code here: http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/source/browse/trunk/python/src/mapreduce/control.py

Answer (score 4):

This is how to access the mapper parameters from the mapper function, using the context module:

```
from mapreduce import context

def riderbee_map(riderbeeRequest):
    ctx = context.get()
    params = ctx.mapreduce_spec.mapper.params
    requestKeyID = params["requestKeyID"]
```